# Mathematical equation for this if condition

Tags: polynomials

Consider a continuous signal u(t) and a binary state b. These two variables are related by the condition:

If u(t) = 0 then b = 0, else b = 1.

How can I relate b and u(t) in one mathematical equation while having nonzero denominator for u = 0?

**Clarification:** The requirement here is to find a tractable expression converting a continuous input to a discrete output. The discrete output should be $0$ if and only if the real input is $0$.

Comment: What is the range of possible values of $u(t)$? Can it be any real number, or are the values limited to an interval $[r,s]$?

Comment: $$b=\mathbf 1_{u(t)\ne0}=\chi_{u(t)\ne0}=[u(t)\ne0]=\ldots$$

Comment: @MPW   u(t) can be any real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the expression
$$-\left\lfloor e^{-u(t)^2}-1\right\rfloor$$
will do the trick. Here "$\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$" is the greatest integer function.

To check this, note that if $u(t)=0$, the expression's value is $-\lfloor e^0-1\rfloor = -\lfloor 0\rfloor = 0$.

On the other hand, note that if $u(t)$ is nonzero, then
$$0<u(t)^2<\infty\tag{squaring}$$
$$-\infty<-u(t)^2<0\tag{mult. by $-1$}$$
$$0<e^{-u(t)^2}<1\tag{exponentiate}$$
$$-1<e^{-u(t)^2}-1< 0\tag{subtr. $1$}$$
so $$\lfloor e^{-u(t)^2}-1\rfloor = -1$$
and thus $$-\lfloor e^{-u(t)^2}-1\rfloor = 1$$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It fits the requirement completely.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know why they voted to put this question on hold. I'm going to try to edit it and vote for reopen.

Comment: The function is required in order to use it in optimization further. Hence, I was actually looking for some smooth function that has nice differentiation properties. But I am not sure if any such fitting can be formulated on this requirement.

Comment: There is no differentiable function on an interval which takes exactly two values. That's because differentiability implies continuity, and the continuous image of a connected space is connected. In the reals, the only connected set with two points (or even countably infinitely many points) is a single point, so the function would be constant.